# Eclipse text-search over all files?

Tags: eclipse, loops, refactoring

I'm optimizing my code at the moment (android game), and wanted to replace all foreach(for(*:*)) with normal fors. Is there a way to find them all? Ctrl-F only looks through the current file and Ctrl-H doesn't seem to find any java constructs (not sure if right word: ifs, whiles, accessors etc.). Preferably without a plugin, but any answer accepted. It would also be nice if there would be a possibility to search for any string (* in Search).

TL;DR: Looking for way to find all foreaches in eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I must say, this sounds like a really strange optimization. Keep in mind that if you have, say, a `LinkedList` you would be far worse of going through a

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    element = list.get(i);
    ...
```

loop, than using an iterator (which for-each loops does). Smells micro-optimizations long way to me.

That said, here's a solution for you:

1. Make sure the root source folder is selected
2. Click Search / File Search
3. Mark Scope as "Selected resources"
4. Mark Regular expression
5. Search for a regular expression such as `for\s*\(.*:`

   The expression matches strings on the form `for`, followed by some white whitespace, followed by `(` followed by some characters, followed by `:` (which kind of characterizes a Java for-each loop).

Comment: I'm also changing any List I find to a normal array[]. I think I've got 2 left in my code, so it won't be that much of a problem.
Thanks, just found out there aren't only 3 options (tabs) when pressing ctrl-h.

Comment: To be honest, that also sounds like a premature optimization. Have you benchmarked your code, and verified that those issues are indeed the bottle-necks of your application?

Comment: Nope, isn't benchmarked yet. I'm just doing everything I can think of.

Comment: Then I bet you're optimizing things that currently take about 1% of the execution time. Suppose you worked really hard one day and eliminated the overhead for lists and loops completely, then you would have improved performance by 1%... If you benchmark your program, and discover that a certain inner loop takes 50% of the time, you perhaps spend 3 minutes rewriting this loop to half its execution time, then all of a sudden you've improved performance by 25%! My point is, that if you're not sure you're working on the bottle-necks, you're probably won't change the performance much at all.

Comment: So I started benchmarking, seems as if everything is running at a good speed, as the drawing seems takes up most of the time (avg 27ms vs 1.5ms for calculating). Thanks for the tipps.

Answer (score 2):

Right-Click on the project, choose search and you're able to replace all `for`-commands with a regular expression like `for(.*;.*;.*)` with other expressions you want to.